# POST data in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How would I post data from one page to another in wordpress.I have tried with the following form :

```
<form action="?page_id=25" method="POST">
```

but then wordpress says page not found when the form is submitted.I then changed permalinks to use %pagename% and still it didn't work,but when I use the url directly it loads the page perfectly.

Is there a different way to POST data in wordpress or is there something I should do so my pages will load?

EDIT

Full code used to submit form

```
<?php 
    echo '<form id="submitForm" method="POST" action="' . get_permalink(25) . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="1" name="id">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="Test" name="name">';
    echo '<a href="javascript:document.getElementById(\'submitForm\').submit();">View</a>';
    echo '</form>';
?>
```

The generated code is as follows :

```
<form id="submitForm" method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/wp/?page_id=25">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="id">
    <input type="hidden" value="Test" name="name">
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('submitForm').submit();">View</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried directly calling url `www.your_site.com/?page_id=25` ? Is it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
  <form action="<?php  echo get_permalink(25); ?>" method="POST">
```

Edit:

Try Below Code , Wordpress has special meaning of `name` variable hence change it

```
    echo '<form id="submitForm" method="POST" action="' . get_permalink(25) . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="1" name="id">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="Test" name="Custom_name">';  // Change the name of the field
    echo '<a href="javascript:document.getElementById(\'submitForm\').submit();">View</a>';
    echo '</form>';
```

Comment: this is the proper way to do it instead of page_id

Comment: Still get page not found

Comment: must be issue with your code, check the form-action in web-console

Comment: Action is right, I'm gonna add the full code I use to submit the form to the question,might be a problem there?